# JavaTesting a method that accepts list as parameters

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing

I need to test a method that accepts list as parameters.

**Method:**

```
public void shuffleCards(List<Integer> data, List<Integer> frequency) {

        Collections.shuffle(data);
        Collections.shuffle(frequency);

    }
```

Should i first create a list of data and frequency, and add values to them and then test or is there any onther way>

After testing i also need to create a table. My table looks like this. I am not sure if my table is correct either.[image]

Comment: By all means - write a JUnit test that creates the two lists you need.  I don't know what that table is about.  I'd rather have a running JUnit test than documentation like that.

Comment: Its for my assignment so i need to do it the way they have told me do. Anyway, is my documentation for this method correct? @duffymo

Comment: What doc ? The table ? Well this depends on the person asking you this. I prefer Javadoc in general :)

Comment: You can execute JUnit tests.  No so with tables or javadocs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not too much to test in that method since you are only using methods from Collections...

maybe validate that lists **data** and **frequency** are not null or empty... the rest (`Collections.shuffle()`) has been already tested by oracle :)

Comment: Hard to expect a specific output from `Collections.shuffle` so I agree with you ! But in this case.